# How to ssh from an ec2 instance to another ec2 instance without storing the public key in one of the instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-iam

I have two ec2 instances one in public subnet and another in private.
I am trying to ssh to the instance which is private subnet from the instance in public subnet. I would not want to store my public key in the public instance to ssh private instance.
Is there any way I can achieve this may be using IAM roles ?

Appreciate the help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K key.pem
ssh –A ec2-user@<PUBLIC-IP-address>
```

After you’re connected to the bastion instance, use SSH to connect to a specific instance using a command like this:

```
 ssh user@<instance-IP-address>
```

Here is a detailed article from AWS on SSH-Agent Forwarding.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/

Comment: Thank you. Is it not possible to do this using IAM roll ? Just curious.